# Why sed not accepting shell variables?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have written this small shell function to modify the samba conf file.
But seems like, it fails somewhere in this line `sed -e "$t1,$t2 d" $CFGFILE > $TMPFILE`. The error is:

```
Doing Samba customization...
/etc/samba/smb.conf
/etc/samba/smb.conf.tmp
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'
```

The same issue i am facing with the last `sed` too:
`sed -e "$t1, $ d" $CFGFILE > $TMPFILE` // Purpose is remove from line number t1 till end

Here is the shell function:

```
updateSmbConf()
{
SMBCFG="$DIR_ETCSAMBA/smb.conf"
SMBCFGTMP="$SMBCFG.tmp"

echo $SMBCFG
echo $SMBCFGTMP

# Fix for bug #3147
sed "s/INSITEONE-CIFS/DELL-CIFS/" $SMBCFG > $SMBCFGTMP
sed "s/InSiteOne CIFS Archive/DCCA CIFS Archive/" $SMBCFG > $SMBCFGTMP
cp $SMBCFGTMP $SMBCFG
rm $SMBCFGTMP

t1=` grep -n "\[Archive\]" $CFGFILE | cut -f1 -d:`
t2=$(($t1+11-1)) # Remove the next 11 lines
sed -e "$t1,$t2 d" $CFGFILE > $TMPFILE
cp $TMPFILE $CFGFILE
rm $TMPFILE

#[SampleHA]
#t1=` grep -n "\[SampleHA\]" $CFGFILE | cut -f1 -d:`
#sed -e "$t1, $ d" $CFGFILE > $TMPFILE
#cp $TMPFILE $CFGFILE
#rm $TMPFILE
}
```

Here is the smb.conf i am trying to modify:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     COMPLETE SMB.CONF
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
# smb.conf is the main Samba configuration file. You find a full commented
# version at /usr/share/doc/packages/samba/examples/smb.conf.SUSE if the
# samba-doc package is installed.
# Date: 2006-07-13
[global]
       guest account = insite1
       oplocks = no
       msdfs root = yes
       workgroup     = INSITEONE-CIFS
       server string = "InSiteOne CIFS Archive"
       security      = SHARE
       syslog        = 0
       max smbd processes = 15
       interfaces = eth* lo
       bind interfaces only = no

#[Archive]
#       hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 10.135.30.135 10.135.30.135
#       hosts deny = ALL
#       vfs objects  = relay:"host = localhost; \
#                             port = 1025;      \
#                             log_level  = 0"
#       comment = InSiteOne Archive File System
#       path = /opt/samba
#       read only = No
#       guest ok = Yes
#       locking = no
[DCCAArchive]
        comment = DCCA Archive File System
        path = /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount/ifm
        read only = No
        public = yes
        writeable = yes
        create mask=0777
        guest ok = Yes
#[SampleHA]
#        comment = High Availability Share
#        path = <Path of Local Archive e.g. /opt/samba3/archive>
#        read only = No
#        guest ok = Yes
#        locking = no
#        hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 OTHERPROXYIP
#        hosts deny = ALL
#        directory mode = 0775
#        create mode = 0664
```

Comment: Try echoing $t1,$t2 before running sed. Do they contain what you think?

Comment: @chroba: That was the first thing i tried. Before wasting 9 hours :(

Comment: Why are you not simply doing `sed '/\[Archive]/!b;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d'`?

Comment: @tripleee: Sorry, i was not aware of this command, and it's not too legible. So `N` i guess is for newline.

Comment: No, `sed` is a (crude, but versatile) programming language. N is the command to fetch the next line and d deletes.

Comment: @choroba: oops t2 was blank !!! Where am i missing? I tried in an individual script it works fine, but in entire script it's blank.

Comment: Your code to find the line number with `grep` is hardly legible, either, and certainly a lot less efficient. Since you are doing other manipulations in `sed` anyway, I would refactor to a single `sed` script, with adequate comments.

Comment: You are using Bash syntax, are you executing the script in plain `sh`?

Comment: @tripleee: yeah, i executed it in plain `sh` in a test script, and it worked. The actual full script is executed using `./scriptName` always as per the release notes, and it's failing. Can you help me identify, what's wrong with `t2`? Why can be done to make it work with `./` syntax?

Comment: If the shebang says `#!/bin/sh` you will need to change it to `#!/bin/bash`, or find and replace all Bash-only constructs with POSIX-compatible code.

Comment: @tripleee: Nope, it does not specify the shell type. `sh` or `bash`, so what needs to be changed here to POSIX compatible? The only place i am stuck is the `sed` delete part, where it is taking input from `t2=$(($t1+11-1))`. Can you suggest it's replacement please?

Comment: One of the suggested self-contained `sed` script will let you get rid of that. For a "simple" substitute, `t2=$(expr "$t1" + 10)`, but I'd recommend simplifying the overall code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged the question [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), so with GNU sed you can just do:

```
sed -i '/\[Archive\]/,+11 d' $SMBCFG
```

This modifies the file in-place, so no need for a tmpfile, and matches the line containing `[Archive]`, so no need for `grep`, and deletes it and the next 11 lines.

Comment: +1 Deleting up to the next line which matches `/^#*\[/` would seem more robust, and does not require GNU `sed`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great !! Sad part is, don't know why you had written the `Archive` in full caps and `CFGFILE` instead of `SMBCFG` to make me run the long install script 8 times to finally find it :-((((((((

Comment: @tripleee, good point, if that's really what's wanted it is more robust. Modifying in-place with `-i` still needs GNU sed IIRC

Comment: @kingsmasher1, there's no reason why, it was just a mistake. You could try actually looking at it to spot the error instead of running it 8 times! ;-)